# Bot Framework channel availability - sms/Twilio

Tags: c#, sms, twilio, botframework

I am using `IDialogContext.PostAsync("[SOME STRING]")` to respond to end users from my bot application. The channel I am testing on is the SMS channel via Twilio. I have noticed that my application successfully executes the `PostAsync` call with no exception being thrown (wrapped it with `try/catch`), but the message is not being delivered consistently. The messages are lengthy and more than 1 segment.

1. Is the message length an issue from a connector perspective because those "dropped" messages don't even show up in my Twilio logs?
2. Is the connector service using some type of queuing mechanism as well and is failing transport to twilio.
3. Is there best practice example of handling transport or unhandled exceptions? Any specific bot example that may have good error handling code? Is there bot code extending some of the Web API 2 global error handling classes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/).

4) Should I be using a raw client and posting to the Connector API instead so that I can handle the HTTP responses I am receiving instead of the `IDialogContext.PostAsync` method?

Comment: Have you checked the Bot Framework site channels for your chatbot? The channel list shows errors when the connector can't communicate with the channel. I also wrap the SendAsync, in the Post handler, in a try/catch.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JoeMayo. I do not use SendAsync, but I do wrap my PostAsync with try/catch and see 0 errors in the site channel. I also looked at twilio usage logs for the phone number I have registered to this bot/channel and don't even see the outbound message attempted.

Comment: Also is there a specific exception type you are catching @JoeMayo ?

Comment: It's FormCancelledException - here's an example: https://github.com/JoeMayo/BotDemos/blob/master/BugFormFlowBot2/Controllers/MessagesController.cs

Comment: hey @JoeMayo, would you mind reviewing one of my bot applications? I'm still running into some transport errors that seem to get consumed and my bot assumes successful delivery. The IActivityLogger I've implemented shows an attempted outgoing activity, but I don't see any log in twilio attempting to send the sms message.